# Display only one entry from the database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, variables

The following code retrieves and displays the correct data from the database however it gets all the data. I need a way to assign each value it retrieves from the database to a PHP variable. For example, if it gets "Joe", "Henry", and "Robert" from the database, I'd like one variable for each of those and right now it returns and array with all the values.

```
<?php
dbCon();
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hosts WHERE name!=''");
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
$res = $row1['name'] . '<br />';
echo $res;
}
?>
```

Comment: I'd want $joe to equal only "Joe" from the database and likewise for the others. As of right now, it just returns/displays an array listing all the entries it finds

Comment: I don't think it would be good practice to do that. If your data ever changes, your code won't handle it. Tell us more about what you want this functionality for.

Comment: I have 2 columns in this database, one named 'id' and one 'name'. One row contains an id of 1 and the name of Joe and the second with the id of 2 and name of Henry. I would like to display Joe and Henry on my page in 2 different places, not in a list

Comment: If you only care about `name` and not `id`, then don't use `*` as part of the `SELECT` statement (use `name`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function echoName($id) {
dbCon();
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hosts WHERE id='$id'");
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
$res = $row1['name'] . '<br />';
echo $res;
}
}
?>


<div id="joe_div">
<?
echoName("1");
?>
</div>

.....


<div id="henry_div">
<?
echoName("2");
?>
</div>
```

Comment: you can call echoName() function from anywhere and echo the name of person by providing it id!

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable variables as such:

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
  $$row1['name'] = $row1['name']
}

echo $Joe; //returns Joe
```

Though I don't know why you would ever need that

Answer (score 0):

```
if it gets "Joe", "Henry", and "Robert" from the database, I'd like one variable for each of those
```

So try this:

```
<?php
 dbCon();
 $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hosts WHERE name!=''");
 while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
 $$row1['name'] = $row1['name'];
}

echo $Joe;
echo $Henry;
echo $Robert;
?>
```

P.S: I don't know why you want to do this, but i am sure you have a better approach to solve your problem.